# How can I make bash ignore a pattern (e.g. .svn) folders when autocompleting directory names?

Tags: bash

When diving into a directory tree (e.g. deep java packages), I will often want bash to autocomplete directory names. Most of the times, the .svn folder will interfere. Can I exclude .svn from being presented as autocomplete candidate?

Comment: My apologies. I actually trusted stackoverflow's search capabilities and (first time in years) didn't consider searching google! Well, now it will appear here too..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
export FIGNORE=.svn
```

Found [here](http://blog.pclewis.com/2010/03/tip-make-bash-tab-completion-ignore-svn-directories/).

Comment: (the second link if you google `bash autocomplete ignore .svn`)

Comment: :P My apologies. I actually trusted stackoverflow's search capabilities and (first time in years) didn't consider searching google!

Answer (score 3):

If you want autocomplete to ignore all hidden directories (not just `.svn`), add the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
bind 'set match-hidden-files off'
```

From `man bash`:

> This variable, when set to On, causes readline to match files whose
>   names begin with a '.' (hidden files) when performing filename
>   completion.  If set to Off,  the leading '.' must be supplied by the
>   user in the filename to be completed.